# How to reassign a value of variable to another variable after a count

Tags: java

I have this code to count up starting with the variable "d" (which can be assigned an integer value 1-7) and counting "n" times (which can be any integer). The count loops back to "1" once the count reaches "7" and assigns the end value to a different variable "j". For example if "5" is entered for "d" and "10" is entered for "n", it counts in the following manner..

"6712345671" (a total of 10 times)

Then it assigns the value of the last integer "1" to the variable "j".

What I need it to do is reassign the value of "j" back to "d". My current code is listed below...

**Code**

```
public void incrementDay3()
{ 
  int i;
  int j = 0;

  for(i = d;i < (d + n);i++)
  {
     j = ((i % 7) + 1);
  }
  System.out.print(j);     
}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: *What I need it to do is reassign the value of "j" back to "d"* - then add the line: `d = j;` at the end of the method ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
 for(i = d;i < (d + n);i++)
  {
     j = ((i % 7) + 1);
  }
```

then just write

```
d = j;
```

Comment: Not sure why that wasn't working before, but when I tried it, it did not work...now it is. User error! :D Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

I was just thinking that maybe your loop is somewhat overkill for what you're trying to do?
I guess you just want to increment a day of week by n days?

If so, you can have it simply like this :

```
public void incrementDay3()
{ 
    d = ((d + n) % 7) + 1;    
}
```